# Use of Cascade in ManyToOne relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, cascade

Is it appropriate to use `Cascade` in both sides of a `ManyToOne` association in Hibernate Entities? To make my question more concrete, let 's assume that someone has the following related Entities:

```
   public class Department
    {
    public long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade=cascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Employee> employees;
    }

    public class Employee{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GeneratedValue.identity)
    public longempid;

    @ManyToOne
    public Department department;
    }
```

In the above relation a `Department` has many `Employees`, hence it is rational to force the `Employees` to be deleted when a `Department` is deleted. Am I right?

However, the owner of the relation is the `Employee`. Therefore my question is, what would be the appropriate-correct choice ragarding where to put the `cascadeType.PERSIST`. Could I choose one of the two sides, according to special needs or could I put it on both sides as well? If I put it on the `Department` side, does the following code save the `Employees` as well, considering the `Employee` is the **owner** of the relation?

```
Employee e1 = new Employee();
Employee e2 = new Employee();
Department d = new Department();
d.getEmployees.add(e1);
d.getEmployees.add(e2);
em.persist(d);
```

I am almost sure the the opposite works if I put the `cascadeType.PERSIST` on the `Employee` side.(Saving the `Employee` would save the `Department` as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in the code you posted, the employee is not the owner of the association. It would if the association was bidirectional, and if the OneToMany association is thus defined with a `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = cascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

(note that I also made the field private. Public fields should never be used).

Regarding the removal of a department: in my company, when a department is removed, all its employees are not automatically fired. They could be assigned to another department, or even stay in the company without being affected to a department, but they're not deleted. I understand your application doesn't necessarily models the real world, but no, it is not necessarily rational to force the employees to be deleted when a department is deleted.

Now, assuming the mapping is as above, yes, you can perfectly add a PERSIST cascade to the OneToMany association. Cascades and ownership are orthogonal notions. If you want the `persist()` operation to be cascaded from a department to its employees (ie. if you want to create employees when creating a department), then add this cascade. For the association to be saved, since the owner side is Employee, the employee.department field will have to be correctly initialized, though.

Comment: You are right with regard to mappedBy, therefore I have updated the question. From your answer I deduce that your suggestion is, that cascadeType.PERSIST can be used in both sides and it works. Am I right?

Comment: I would like of course to try it, but something hinders me to use Hibernate on my PC. See my relevant answer to conceive the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638930/hibernate-does-not-create-table-in-the-database

Comment: If the cascade PERSIST is on the Department (not owner) side, then by doing department.getEmployees().add(new Employee()); session.persist(department), it saves the Employee but it has null at the Foreign Key Department_ID column. Obviously it needs first employee.setDepartment(department);

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "For the association to be saved, since the owner side is Employee, the employee.department field will have to be correctly initialized, though"