# Hibernate does not create Table in the database

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, relational-database

I am using `PostgreSQL` and I am trying to run a simple `Hibernate` application, in particular the application decribed in the [page](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/). My hibernate.cfg.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql:testDB2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">user</property>


        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
       <!--  <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property> -->

        <mapping class="com.al.hibmaventest.Department"/>
        <mapping class="com.al.hibmaventest.Employee"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My `pom.xml` (when using maven) is:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.al.hibmaventest</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibMavenTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I use the `main()` as it is in the link:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Department department = new Department();
        department.setDepartmentName("Sales");
        session.persist(department);

        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Nina", "Mayers", "111");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Tony", "Almeida", "222");

        emp1.setDepartment(department);
        emp2.setDepartment(department);

        session.persist(emp1);
        session.persist(emp2);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }
```

However it is impossible to get the application work, namely to do hibernate create the Tables in the Database and insert the value. I receive always, whatever I tried, the same error:

```
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Hibernate: insert into Department (DEPT_NAME) values (?)
Mai 19, 2013 6:56:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
Mai 19, 2013 6:56:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: ERROR: relation "department" does not exist
  Position: 13
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.al.hibmaventest.Department]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2643)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:592)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:596)
    at com.al.hibmaventest.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "department" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
    ... 14 more
```

"Relation department does not exist" on line :

```
session.persist(department);
```

I have tried it without `maven` as well, exactly the same error. In order to preempt some readers, the Table (relation) "department" is never created in the database. Even if I create it manually in the Database(what is hibernate expected to do), the error remains the same. I think it is a problem in the creation of the sessions or in the connection withe database.

Does `PostgreSQL` need configuration to accept `Hibernate` connection?. Can the problem come from the `JNDI` as the message says "Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured"?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The property is `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, instead of `hibernate.hbm2dll.auto`.

> DDL = Data Definition Language
>
> DLL = Dynamically Loaded Library

Comment: Yes! It finally works! I have had this problem for a month and I could not find it. I have set another question on the site, but I received irrelevent answers like: "You should create the Table manually" an so on. If I could donate you 200 points I would do it. Thanks.

Comment: @arjacsoh: in your other question you did **not** show us your `hibernate.cfg.xml` (and I still believe that the tables of a database should be created using a controlled script rather than some "magic" inside the ORM)

Answer (score 1):

The question has been correctly answered. By the way, I'd like to add something. You put

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">user</property>
```

It's not a good option to change postgres password default (it carries security problems), and it isn't secure using postgres user as owner in a DB. For more information, see the following link https://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install/325596#325596
Sorry for this disgression, but I think it could be useful.